# Julia Jupyter Notebook persists despite logout from browser

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook

Running Julia in a terminal (macOS) and then launching a Jupyter notebook

```
julia> using IJulia

julia> notebook(detached=true)
```

This works fine.  However when I log out of the notebook and closing the browser, there is still a jupyter-notebook running and I have to `kill -2 pid` to make it go away.

Is this expected behaviour?  Is there a parameter I need to set somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behaviour for the way you've called notebook. The server doesn't stop when your browser page is closed (you might open another, for example!). Using the detached keyword argument means the server process is started in the background, so doesn't block the Julia session you started it from, so you'd have to do extra work if you wanted to stop it from there. From [the IJulia readme](https://github.com/JuliaLang/IJulia.jl/blob/master/README.md#running-the-ijulia-notebook):

> You can use `notebook(detached=true)` to launch a notebook server in the background that will persist even when you quit Julia